# What type of array is this?

Tags: javascript

Or is it not an array? and where can I find information about creating something with this structure?

```
[
    ['Firefox',   45.0],
    ['IE',       26.8],
    ['Safari',    8.5],
    ['Opera',     6.2],
    ['Others',   0.7]
]
```

Comment: Multi-dimensional array?

Comment: If you're asking about the syntax, that's the "Array literal syntax". Check out the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a multi-dimensional array.

```
var x = [
    ['Firefox',   45.0],
    ['IE',       26.8],
    ['Safari',    8.5],
    ['Opera',     6.2],
    ['Others',   0.7]
];
console.log(x[3][1]);
```

​
Would result in 6.2

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/evrRE/)**.

Comment: how would I add new values to the array or update existing values?

Comment: Updating would just be a matter of referencing the element you want to change. For example, to change the value of Safari from 8.5 to 8.6, you would use `x[2][1] = 8.6;`. To add a new value, you could do: `x.push(['foo',10]);`

Answer (score 5):

Simply put, it's an array, of arrays. :)

If your object (the multi-dimensional array) were called `testObject` for example, you could traverse it like so...

```
for (var i = 0; i < testObject.length; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < testObject[i].length; j++)
    {
        alert(testObject[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: for (var i in testObject) - probably not the best way to iterate through array, for (var i = 0; i < testObject.length; i++) - much safer

Comment: Eeeck.  You should NEVER traverse arrays with `for (var i in xxx)` because that gets properties of the object too, not just array elements.  This is a bad practice.  Arrays should be iterated with `for (var i = 0, len = testArray.length; i < len; i++)` or something equivalent.